# How to specify files to ignore when push to Cloud Foundry using cf-gradle-plugin

Tags: gradle, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I am trying to deploy my static application to cloud foundry using **cf-gradle-plugin**.

in my gradle file I have defined buildpack:

```
buildpack = "https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git#v1.1.0"
```

and files to deploy:

```
file = file('.')
```

I would like to specify which files should be not pushed to the cf. I have tried to do it by specifying .**cfignore** file in the root directory, but it does not work. Does anybody know how to filter files which should be deployed to CF when using cf-gradle-plugin and staticfile buildpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to filter files with the v1 version of the Gradle plugin. As you probably saw from your [issue on the project](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/issues/330), supporting .cfignore should be supported in v2.

For now, you could use Gradle to package the contents of your project into a zip archive, using the sophisticated [filtering rules that Gradle supports](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html), then specify the zip file in the Cloud Foundry Gradle plugin.